# how do you pass an array to a template function?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

In my main I create an object from a template class, then I call my sort method (template method) 
However it get a error in my main.obj file.

error:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SelectionSort<int [0]>::IterativeSort(int * const,unsigned int)" ............
```

Call in main:

```
SelectionSort<int[]> smallArraySort;
smallArraySort.IterativeSort(smallArray, smallSize);
```

Header file: SelectionSort.h

```
template <class T>
class SelectionSort
{
    public:
        void IterativeSort(T data, unsigned int size);
        void RecursiveSort(T data, unsigned int size);

};
```

sort code: SelectionSort.cpp

```
#include "SelectionSort.h"

template<class T>
void SelectionSort<T> ::IterativeSort(T data, unsigned int size)
{
    int temp = data[0];
    int greaterNum = 0


        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        for (unsigned int inner = index; inner < size; inner++)
        {
            if (temp>data[inner])
            {
                greaterNum = temp;
                temp = data[inner];
                data[inner] = greaterNum;

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets ask that a little differently: Is the *implementation* of `SelectionSort<T>::IterativeSort` as you have posted it here, in a header included within `main.cpp` (or whatever you called it)? I.e its *not* implemented (as you have it here) in some other .cpp file, *right* ?

Comment: Well, your update with file names answers that question. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you *implement* the methods of the template in a `.cpp` file where they cannot be seen when they need to be instantiated.  In general, [templates must be defined in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/501250).

To solve the problem, eliminate your `SelectionSort.cpp` file by moving its definitions into `SelectionSort.h`.